# How to Link dropdown list content controls?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to make a word document just a little bit faster/more accurate.

So I have an agreement form where users input their name in a blank at the beginning of the form, then have to input their name again at the end of the form next to their signature, along with each person having an assigned serial number unique to them that they also need to input.

Is there some sort of "If, Then" argument that could make the second name equal the first? Likewise, could I tweak that argument for the serial number block? Because each name corresponds with exactly one serial number.[image: Example of points to be linked]

I know how I would do it in excel, but that would require me to draft an entirely new form (the form pictured is edited for brevity and clarity)

Any help is much appreciated.

tigl

Comment: Either map the content control to a custom xml part so that entering the value once updates all other linked content controls, or use one of the built-in ones found under Insert | Quick Parts | Document Property.

Comment: See my answers here:
==================== - [Is there a way to make two parts of the document linked? So that if I change one part of the document the other automatically updates?](https://superuser.com/questions/1706812/is-there-a-way-to-make-two-parts-of-the-document-linked-so-that-if-i-change-one/1706847#1706847) - [Customize existing MS Word Template document's variables & Content Controls](https://superuser.com/questions/1708574/customize-existing-ms-word-template-documents-variables-content-controls)